# Splitting the dollar - Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

Two players bargain over how to split \$10. Each player $i \in \{1, 2\}$ chooses a number $s_i \in [0, 10]$ (which does not need to be an integer). Each player's payoff is the money he receives. We consider two allocation rules. In each case, if $s_1 + s_2 \leq 10$, each player gets his chosen amount s; and the rest is destroyed.

1. In the first case, if $s_1 + s_2 > 10$, both players get zero. What are the (pure strategy) Nash equilibria?
   Answer: All couples such that $s_1 + s_2 = 10$ and $(s_1= 10, s_2= 10)$.
   My question; why is $(10,10)$ Nash equilibrium? Neither one will get money in that case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Reminder: A Nash Equilibrium is a strategy profile such that no player has a profitable deviation. It has nothing to do with *global* optimality or *global* maximization of payoff. Instead, for each player, it is the strategy that maximizes his payoff given the rest are following the equilibrium strategies.

In our case: Suppose we both say $s_i=10$. Then as you mentioned, we get $0$.

Do any of us have a profitable deviation?

No. Regardless of what you say, you will still get $0$, so you don't have a profitable deviation, and $(10,10)$ is an equilibrium.

To clarify, $(10,5)$ is not an equilibrium, since in this case, I get $0$, but if I offer $5$ instead of $10$ I'll get more strictly, so it is a profitable deviation. This is why only $(10,10)$ is an equilibrium because no one can unilaterally reduce the sum below $10$ and actually get a nonzero payoff.

Comment: What is \emph{global}? Is it just some MathJax without the dollar signs?

Comment: Wanted to write italics and forgot it's not latex. :D

Comment: Well, you have corrected it now so it should be all fine.

Comment: So I have another question: is (10,0) or (0,10) Nash Equilibrium?

Comment: Yes. If you say $10$ and I say $0$, you get $10$ and I get $0$. If I say anything else, I'll still get $0$. If you say anything else, you'll get less than $10$. Both have no profitable deviation = it's an equilibrium.